# The getifaddrs function

Tags: linux, networking

Could someone please explain to me why getifaddrs returns the same interface once with AF_PACKET and second AF_INET as two different interfaces?

When it is AF_PACKET the MAC address can be obtain by doing a cast to sockaddr_ll. However this struct has 20 bytes while the sockaddr_in 16. Why is this cast safe?

Thanks,

Comment: Showing the code would make this question better.

Comment: I have used to code from http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getifaddrs.3.html

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that this is roughly what is happening:

All sockaddr_* have the same common header fields (sa_family, sa_len, sa_data) in this order. This guarantees that all sockaddr_* instances are at least 20 bytes and can be safely overlaid/aliased with a sockaddr, albeit with a collection of casts that makes those of us priveleged to work in more strongly typed languages weep. The thing that makes the case safe in the reverse direction is that (hopefully) nobody made any mistakes setting sa_family when implementing getifaddrs.

Answer (score 0):

1 The function `getifaddrs()` returns the network addresses of a network interface. Usually, network interfaces can have multiple addresses.

- AF_PACKET: link/ethernet address of an network interface
- AF_INET:   IPv4 address of the network interface
- AF_INET6:  IPv6 address of the network interface

Assume you assign one IPv4 and one IPv6 addresses to the network interface "eth0". Then, the function `getifaddrs()` returns three entries for "eth0":

- one contains the MAC address
- one contains the assigned IPv4 address
- one contains the assigned IPv6 address

2. The function `getifaddrs()` returns a **pointer** to a `struct sockaddr`. Thus, the implementation can do something similar to the following:

   `...
   struct sockaddr_in6 *socka6 = malloc(sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6));
   struct ifaddrs *ifa = malloc(sizeof(struct ifaddrs);
   ...
   ifa->ifa_addr= (struct sockaddr *) socka6;
   ...`